# Protobuf-net Root-Level List Serialization AsReference

Tags: serialization, reference, protobuf-net

I am attempting to serialize a collection of objects using the protobuf-net library.  I am running into an issue where the top-level objects in the collection are not being set up as references in a graph, so when they are referenced further down in the serialized children, they are re-serialized and created as references at that point.  Is there a way to get the top level objects to be serialized as references?  I've read several conflicting posts that seem to indicate protobuf-net now supports this, while other posts seem to suggest creating a wrapper around the top-level object to enable this behavior.  Thanks...

Here is the sample program showing my problem.  As you can see, the references are not equal.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace ProtoBufTest
{
    [ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]
    public class Foo
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, AsReference=true)]
        public FooChild Child;

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public Guid Id;
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class FooChild
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, AsReference=true)]
        public Foo Parent;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>()
            {
                new Foo() { Child = new FooChild(), Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
            };

            foos[0].Child.Parent = foos[0];

            var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(foos);

            Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(clone[0], clone[0].Child.Parent));
            Console.WriteLine(clone[0].Id == clone[0].Child.Parent.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do actually mean *the root object* (i.e. the object passed into `Serialize`), then that should simply work, for example:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Bar
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Bar = new Bar() };
        foo.Bar.Foo = foo;
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(foo);

        // writes: True
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(clone, clone.Bar.Foo));
    }
}
```

If it *isn't* working, then I suspect it isn't actually the *root*, but is just something high up in the graph (but non-root) - in which case adding `AsReference=true` should fix it.

Note that I'm also overdue a public release, but the source code now has much better support for expressing this at the contract level - which will be included in the next build. For example (working from memory here):

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

This then implicitly assumes that any `Foo` members should be serialized as references ***unless*** they are explicitly disabled (`AsReference=false`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response - btw, your library has been great for our application and is working for all of our WCF services with the exception of these few.  Let me clarify my question a bit as I see I did not ask it very well.  The root object that I am attempting to serialize is IList<Foo> - Foo is marked with the AsReferenceDefault=true ProtoContract attribute, yet those Foo objects in the List do not seem to be treated as references.

Comment: @user1863798 can you perhaps present a short but complete example I can use to repro? (and to serve as an integration test to ensure that it stays working once tweaked)

Comment: I found this link from a couple of years back - [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100647/issue-while-serializing-graphs-with-protobuf-net) - adding an outer root object definitely works around this issue for us, but the concern with a large dev team is that others will not know about this restriction when writing new web services in the future.  So if you are able to resolve this in a future release, we'd be very appreciative.  Thanks for all your hard work on the project.  Cheers.

Comment: Ouch! Stumbled on this Stackoverflow when looking for something else (different case of an unexpected extra instance). I've basically been setting up serialisation callbacks to clear and restore back referencing in order to get around this issue. Would love an update.